# Is it possible to have pre-load elements in webforms?

Tags: 8, forms, webforms

I have to add two elements (checkbox, texfield) in the creation process of the webform. This is because I want a simple terms and conditions inside all webforms. How can I do this?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Drupal Answers and thanks for your question. Unfortunately it's not completely clear what you're asking. Can you explain what you mean by "pre-load an element"? What kind of element is this about? Is this in the webform creation process? Which problem are you trying to solve by pre-loading an element?

Comment: Hi @marcvangend, I have to add two elements (checkbox - texfield) in the creation process of the webform this is because I want a simple terms and conditions inside of all webforms. I tried with form_alter but I had problems with submission.

Comment: OK, I see. Feel free to edit an update the original question so others don't have to read through the comments to obtain all information. Personally I don't know the answer to your question, but if you know PHP you could look at the [Webform Default Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_default_fields) module to learn how they did that in Drupal 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could pre-load the elements in a [hook_ENTITY_TYPE_create](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_create/8.4.x) hook:

*mymodule.module:*

```
  /**
   * Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_create() for webform entities.
   */
  function mymodule_webform_create(\Drupal\webform\WebformInterface $webform) {

    $elements = [
      'name' => [
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => 'name',
      ],
      'other' => [
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => 'other',
      ],
    ];

    $webform->setElements($elements);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Webforms now has a "prepopulate" option for most fields.  Use the URL query string to populate a field that has been enabled for prepopulation

Comment: The question is regarding adding some elements to all forms by default, the 'prepopulate' you are referring to is for adding default values to already existing elements.

Comment: Good point!  Well, as chance would have it, I am working on a custom module to do something like that.